Creating batch classes on BigBlueButton using greenlight V3
I've been using greenlight v2 until very recently, and since I'm dealing with large number of classes every semester I came up with this code to create batch classes in greenlight using Ruby on rails:

classNames = ["Test1", "Test2"]



7.times.map{

     roomNames = []

     for i in 0..Room.all.length-1

          roomName = Room.all[i].name

          roomNames .append(roomName)

     end

     for i in 0..classNames.length

          className= classNames[i]

          if roomNames.include?(className) == true

               classNames.delete(className)

          end

     end

}



urls = Array.new(classNames.length)

moderatorCodes = classNames.length.times.map{([*1..9].shuffle[0..0].join).concat([*'a'..'z'].shuffle[0..4].join)}

for i in 0..classNames.length

className= classNames[i]

moderatorCode= moderatorCodes[i]

urls[i] = Room.create(user_id: 1, name: className, room_settings: "{\"muteOnStart\":true,\"requireModeratorApproval\":false,\"anyoneCanStart\":false,\"joinModerator\":false}",moderator_access_code: moderatorCode).uid

puts [classNames[i],urls[i],moderatorCodes[i]].inspect

end

Which gave me an array of class names, urls and randomly created moderator codes for each class.
Now in the new version of greenlight (v3), there seems to be no moderator_access_code attribute.
I would appreciate it if you could help me come up with a solution to reach the same array of [name, url, moderator code] in greenlight v3 using Ruby on rails.
I couldn't find any solutions online
